# How to correctly create a polygon from an extent?

Tags: openlayers

I'm tying to create a new polygon based on some calculated extent. I'm doing this way, as suggested by [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html):

```
let newPolygon = new Polygon().fromExtent(newExtent);
let newFeature = new Feature({
    geometry: newPolygon,
});
```

This is giving me an error in the `new Polygon()` line:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

`newExtent` is an array and is in accordance with the [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_extent.html#~Extent) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is

```
import {fromExtent} from 'ol/geom/Polygon';

let newPolygon = fromExtent(newExtent);
```